# JavaFX print custom paper size

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX, I want to print out a photo to 10x15 paper. There are some Paper constansts, but there is no 100x150 mm constant.

Is it possible to create an own Paper to use it in PageLayout?

Thanks.

```
PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.JAPANESE_POSTCARD, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.EQUAL);
        double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
        double scaleY = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() / node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
    node.getTransforms().add(new Scale(scaleX, scaleY));
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
    if (job != null) {
        System.out.println("Job created!");
        boolean success = job.printPage(node);
        if (success) {
            System.out.println("Job successfully finished!");
            job.endJob();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Job NOT successful!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor of Paper is package-private so you can't create a Paper size apart from the standard sizes listed in the class.

However you could create a custom size with reflection:

```
Constructor<Paper> c = Paper.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class,
                                         double.class, double.class, Units.class);
c.setAccessible(true);
Paper photo = c.newInstance("10x15", 100, 150, MM);
```

I have not tested if that works properly though.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the class PrintHelper which has access to the package private constructor of Paper.

```
Paper photo = PrintHelper.createPaper("10x15", 100, 150, Units.MM);
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's so lame that you have to do that... i mean, constructor = package private on that?  wuuuuuut?